# How to list last modified file in S3 using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to get the last modified file in S3 using the following:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    import boto3
    
    bucket_name = "arn:aws-us-gov:s3:::some_bucket_name/some_folder/"
    
    get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']
    last_added = [obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified)][0]
```

...and although things look correct, I keep getting the error:

```
"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid bucket name \"arn:aws-us-gov:s3:::some_bucket_name/some_folder/\": Bucket name must match the regex \"^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]{1,255}$\" or be an ARN matching the regex \"^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z\\-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\\-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1,63}$\"",
```

What am I missing in the bucket name? I copied the ARN from the console and still cannot seem to produce the expected result. I'm not a RegEx guru so it's hard for me to discern what could be missing from the arn. To test, I replaced the bucket name with some random name and got an error that the bucket does not exist; as expected. I'm slightly confused what the issue is. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Youn don't need to put the full ARN, just the `some_bucket_name` in your case. See the documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2

Comment: The bucket name you want to use is "some_bucket_name", not the full ARN to the bucket.  Also, if you don't use a paginator, you will only get the first 1000 objects in the bucket, at most.

Comment: I see the issue I was having with the bucket_name: I was trying to use the full path of the files' location rather than just the actual bucket name. I'll have to do a little more digging on how to add the rest of the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've resolved the "issue" and now have what I need.

```
import boto3
    
bucket_name = "actual_bucket_name"
prefix = "path/to/files/"
    
get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%s'))

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/' ['Contents']
last_added = [obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified)][0]
```

Thank you for the pointers. I was readin through the documentation, however, we know how it can be after staring at walls of text after a while. The "issue" was me not acutely comprehending.

Comment: For anyone trying to use the above the second to last line is missing a paren. It should be `objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/')['Contents']`
Additionally, mine sorted in ascending order so if you want the latest modified / last added, you should do [-1], not [0] in the last line of code above